# List contatining objects from a unmanaged class is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-2015, c++-cli

I am referencing an unmanaged class from a managed class I am writing in C++/CLI. Declaring an object by itself works fine, but when I try to create a list of the unmanaged objects I get the following error from Visual Studio:

```
"umngObject *" is not a valid generic argument.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code snippet:

```
#include "umngObject.h"
...
umngObject* foo;  //appears to work fine
List<umngObject*> _foobar; //gives the error
```

Comment: The error says what you're doing wrong -- you can't store pointers to unmanaged objects in the managed `List` type. C++/CLI allows you to write "glue" code between the two worlds, but you still cannot mix them directly. The solution depends on what you're trying to achieve, exactly -- is managed code supposed to do something with the list or do you just need a container a la `std::vector`?

Comment: I just need a container.

Comment: std::vector is an appropriate container.   You could technically use a `List<IntPtr>` but the casting isn't exactly great and nothing helps you get the memory management right.